# how to get all column values of a single row in android parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform

I want to get **all** the data(i.e. column values) of the **first row**, which includes the 'objectId', 'ClientName','Session','myDate','createdAT', 'updatedAt' and 'ACL'.

How can I achieve this, thanks for the help.

[image]

Comment: read the manual Rest API, use curl to execute a GET on your testClass ... https://parse.com/docs/rest#objects

Comment: @Ricky Zheng - please accept my answer below as correct if it helped you achieve what you needed

Answer (score 3):

You just query the table for the first object:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("GameScore");
query.whereEqualTo("playerEmail", "dstemkoski@example.com");
query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
  public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
    if (object == null) {
      Log.d("score", "The getFirst request failed.");
    } else {
      Log.d("score", "Retrieved the object.");
    }
  }
});
```

After this query, object will be the first object in the table, and you can access its values with the parse getter methods.  I suggest you read the parse docs:  https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#queries